# RegEx for WordPress Find and Replace

Tags: regex, wordpress

I am looking for a RegEx that will match a complete  tag of an unknown length where a given keyword is within the tag. So when I am looking for the string "example" I want to match the whole tag:

```
<a href="https://www.justsomestuff.com/andevenmorestuffnotof interest" target="_new" and so on>example</a>
```

example

As I have no understanding for RegEx at all, I didn't know how to start at all.

Comment: Where are you planning to have this RegExp run from? Can you give us a bit more info on your overall use case? What have you tried, and where are you getting stuck? Can you share your attempt as a [mre]?

Comment: Just updated my post as the HTML tag was interpreted. I want the whlote HTML <a>-tag removed, from <a> to </a>

Comment: Where is this HTML tag? In a PHP variable? In a post or page? Are you looking to remove it on the server side or on the client side?

Comment: I want to use it in the GUI form of the WordPress-plugin "Real-Time Find and Replace" where you have fields to enter what you are looking for and what do replace it with. As I wan to remove the complete tag, I would just insert the RegEx in the first field and let the second one empty.

Comment: If you want to remove the `<a ...>` and `</a>` tags, but keep the `example` anchor text, then you could use just use [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). That'd be much simpler and more reliable than a regex.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to keep "example", I want it to be removed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend finding introductory material on regex and having a read through. This will greatly help you understand and implement the solution you need. Wordpress is implemented in PHP, so you will likely want to [find materials regarding PCRE](https://www.php.net/pcre), which is a regex implementation commonly used with PHP.

To match your example, I would consider this regex:

```
<[^>]*>example<\/[^>]*>
```

Know that processing HTML with regex is not often advised because HTML can be more complicated than regex can handle. You may wish to consider HTML parsers instead.

Comment: Thank you for that. Works for my given example, but doesn't work for <a><b>example</b></a>. It machtes the <b> tag in this case. I tried to add [Aa] at any position of your statement but couldn't get it to work this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example:

```
<a\b[^>]*>.*?example.*?<\/a>
```

Here is a little test: https://regex101.com/r/eBj9tj/1

Or you can test it in PHP:

```
$contents = [];
$contents[] = '<a href="https://www.justsomestuff.com/andevenmorestuffnotof interest">example</a>';
$contents[] = '<a href="https://www.justsomestuff.com/andevenmorestuffnotof interest" target="_new" and so on>example</a>';
$contents[] = '<a href="https://www.justsomestuff.com/andevenmorestuffnotof interest" target="_new" and so on><b>example</b></a>';
$contents[] = '<a href="https://www.justsomestuff.com/andevenmorestuffnotof interest" target="_new" and so on><b><span>example</span></b></a>';
$contents[] = '<div><a href="https://www.justsomestuff.com/andevenmorestuffnotof interest" target="_new" and so on><b><span>example</span></b></a></div>';
$contents[] = '<div><a href="https://www.justsomestuff.com/andevenmorestuffnotof interest" target="_new" and so on><b><span>next example</span></b></a></div>';
$contents[] = '<a href="https://www.justsomestuff.com/andevenmorestuffnotof interest" target="_new" and so on><b><span>example</span></b></a> <div><a href="https://www.justsomestuff.com/andevenmorestuffnotof interest" target="_new" and so on><b><span>example</span></b></a></div>';

$keyword = 'example';
$pattern = '/<a\b[^>]*>.*?'.$keyword.'.*?<\/a>/i';

for($i = 0; $i < count( $contents ); $i++ ) {
    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all( $pattern, $contents[$i], $matches );
    if(!empty($matches[0])){
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($matches[0]); $j++) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($matches[0][$j]).'<br />';
        }
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```